# Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios

Apple LLVM 8.1 Error Group
Every time I build,xcode show the error,and the error is different ,this time maybe this VC and next time other VCs!
anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Xcode > Project > Target > Build Phase> Compile Sources` check if any file is duplicated or any files show with red color if so delete them and do a clean build.

Also try, deleting derived data : ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData